# Why is find_withtag wont work in python

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter, tags

This is part of my code, the id of image wont print even I use the withtag function. I think the function canvas.delete won't work is also the same problem, it seem the tag is inserted as "123","456". However, the tag I expected to use and get is 123 instead of '123'. And I guess it's the main problem I can't get the id I want with the findtag function.

```
           CurrentImage=Note[NoteIndexLocal]
           Temp=canvas.create_image(XShow,YShow,image=CurrentImage,tag=123)
           print canvas.find_withtag(123)  #This Wont Work,printed()
           canvas.delete(123)              #This Wont Work
           print canvas.gettags(Temp)      #printed '123'
```

Comment: use `str(123)` instead of `123`

Answer (score 0):

From: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm

> Tags are symbolic names attached to items. Tags are ordinary **strings**,
>   and they can contain anything except whitespace (as long as they don’t
>   look like item handles).

Use `str(123)` instead of `123`

---

**EDIT:** correct answer is in text from doc `"as long as they don’t look like item handles"`. Number `123` looks like item handle (print `Temp` to see how it looks like) so it doesn't work. Use text like `"a123"` and it will work.

Comment: It still print nothing.

Comment: A=str(123)
          Temp=canvas.create_image(XShow,YShow,image=CurrentImage,tag=A)
print canvas.find_withtag(A)  #This Wont Work

Comment: see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method  - probably `create_images` doesn't use `tag=` , it uses `tags=` (with `s` in name)

Comment: answer is in text from doc `"as long as they don’t look like item handles"` :) . Number `123` looks like item handle (print `Temp` to see how it looks like) so it doesn't work. Use text like "a123" and it will work.